# Cant edit a binary program using fwrite and writing an int?

Tags: c, linux, fopen, elf, fwrite

I'm trying to make a program to write a number into two different file(binary elf file) offsets using `fwrite` and `fseek` but both seems to report writing and seeking correctly but `objdump -s 0x2db0 -n 0x16 test`seems to show no change. `fwrite` and `fseek` called as:

```
error = fwrite((void*)&value, sizeof(value), 1, file);
seek_error = fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);
```

whole program is executed like bellow and is supposed to write `0x119e` at offset `0x2db0` and `0x01`:

```
./patch test 0x01 0x2db0 0x119e
```

so instead of seeing `119e` at both offsets when running `objdump` no change seems to happen at all.

whole Source code is:(mostly checking for functions return values)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <zconf.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    long error, seek_error;
    long value, offset;

    if (argc < 5){
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect arg number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "ab");
    if (file == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error openning File\n");
        perror("fopen() :");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\t\t File opened successfully\n");

    value = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 16); /* convert target value to int */
    if (value == LONG_MIN || value == LONG_MAX){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling strtol\n");
        perror("strtol() :");
        exit(1);
    }

    offset = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 16);
    printf("offset is %ld\n", offset);
    if (offset == LONG_MIN || offset == LONG_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling strtol during offset\n");
        perror("strtol() :");
        exit(1);
    }

    seek_error = fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET); /* From start go to end*/
    if (seek_error != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling fseek\n");
        perror("fseek(): ");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File position is: 0x%lx\n", ftell(file));

    error = fwrite((void*)&value, sizeof(value), 1, file);
    if (error != 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling write\n");
        perror("write() :");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Number of bytes written %ld\n", error);

    offset = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 16);
    printf("offset is %ld\n", offset);
    if (offset == LONG_MIN || offset == LONG_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling strtol during scond offset\n");
        perror("strtol() :");
        exit(1);
    }

    seek_error = fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);  /* Seek to the new offset */
    if (seek_error != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling second fseek\n");
        perror("fseek(): ");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File position is: 0x%lx\n", ftell(file));

    error = fwrite((void*)&value, sizeof(value), 1, file);
    if (error != 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling write\n");
        perror("write() :");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Number of bytes written %ld\n", error);

    fflush(file);   /* flush changes not nesessecarly */
    error = fclose(file);
    if (error != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "error closing file\n");
        perror("close() :");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the file in append mode with `fopen(argv[1], "ab")`. So all writes are done at the end of the file, ignoring the position you seeked to.

Use `fopen(argv[1], "rb+")` instead. `r` means to open it in read mode, so the file isn't emptied first, and `+` means that writing is also allowed.

Comment: Thank's alot. it worked now but why ```fseek``` did'nt report an error and ```ftell``` says that that file is correctly seeked

Comment: fseek works, it's just useless. When you write something, it automatically seeks to the end first.